# Calculate with regex group matches?

Tags: php, regex

Is it possible to calculate with regex group matches?

String:

```
(00) Bananas
...
(02) Apples (red ones)
...
(05) Oranges
...
(11) Some Other Fruit
...
```

If the difference between the numbers at the beginning of each row is 3 or less, remove the "..." inbetween. So the string should be returned like this:

```
(00) Bananas
(02) Apples (red ones)
(05) Oranges
...
(11) Some Other Fruit
```

Regex:

```
$match = '/(*ANYCRLF)\((\d+)\) (.+)$
\.{3}
\((\d+)\) (.+)/m';
```

Now the tricky part is how to grab the matches and add some to a condition like

```
if($3-$1 >= 3) {
  //replace
}
```

Test: http://codepad.viper-7.com/f6iI4m

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you could do it with `preg_replace_callback()`.

```php
$callback = function ($match) {
    if ($match[3] <= $match[2] + 3) {
        return $match[1];
    } else {
        return $match[0];
    }
};

$newtxt = preg_replace_callback('/(^\((\d+)\).+$)\s+^\.{3}$(?=\s+^\((\d+)\))/m', $callback, $txt);
```

```
/(^\((\d+)\).+$)\s+^\.{3}$(?=\s+^\((\d+)\))/m
```

Here's the pattern in pieces:

```
(^\((\d+)\).+$)      # subpattern 1, first line; subpattern 2, the number
\s+^\.{3}$           # newline(s) and second line ("...")
(?=\s+^\((\d+)\))    # lookahead that matches another numbered line 
                     # without consuming it; contains subpattern 3, next number
```

Thus, the entire pattern's match is the first two lines (i.e., numbered line and '...' line).

If the difference in numbers is greater than 3, replace with original text in `$match[0]` (i.e., no change). If difference is less than or equal to 3, replace with first line only (found in `$match1]`).

Comment: @Martin Glad to hear! I wasn't sure if there were other cases I hadn't accounted for, such as multiple "..." lines in a row. If you do find other cases to account for, I'd be happy to make modifications.

Answer (score 0):

You could employ [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) and use any php code to return the replacement string, the callback receives the captures. However for you output you would have to get overlapping matches for replacement:

1. compare `(00) Bananas` vs `(02) Apples` -> `2-0=2` **replace**
2. compare `(02) Apples` vs `(05) Oranges` -> `5-2=3` **replace**
3. ...

But since the input's `(02) Apples` part have been used for a previous match you it won't be picked up for the second time.

#### edit:

Here's a regexp based solutinon with lookaheads, credit goes to Wiseguy:

```
$s = "(00) Bananas
...
(02) Apples (red ones)
...
(05) Oranges
...
(11) Some Other Fruit
...";

$match = '/(*ANYCRLF)\((\d+)\) (.+)$
\.{3}
(?=\((\d+)\) (.+))/m';

// php5.3 anonymous function syntax
$s = preg_replace_callback($match, function($m){
    if ($m[3] - $m[1] <= 3) {
        print preg_replace("/[\r\n]+.../", '', $m[0]);
    } else {
        print $m[0];
    }
}, $s);
echo $s;
```

Here is my first take, based on the logic "find the dots then see the previous / next lines":

```
$s = "(00) Bananas
...
(02) Apples (red ones)
...
(05) Oranges
...
(11) Some Other Fruit
...
(18) Some Other Fruit
...
(19) Some Other Fruit
...
";

$s = preg_replace("/[\r\n]{2}/", "\n", $s);

$num_pattern = '/^\((?<num>\d+)\)/';
$dots_removed = 0;

preg_match_all('/\.{3}/', $s, $m, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
foreach ($m[0] as $i => $dots) {
    $offset = $dots[1] - ($dots_removed * 4); // fix offset of changing input

    $prev_line_end = $offset - 2; // -2 since the offset is pointing to the first '.', prev char is "\n"
    $prev_line_start = $prev_line_end; // start the search for the prev line's start from its end
    while ($prev_line_start > 0 && $s[$prev_line_start] != "\n") {
        --$prev_line_start;
    }

    $next_line_start = $offset + strlen($dots[0]) + 1;
    $next_line_end = strpos($s, "\n", $next_line_start);
$next_line_end or $next_line_end = strlen($s);

    $prev_line = trim(substr($s, $prev_line_start, $prev_line_end - $prev_line_start));
    $next_line = trim(substr($s, $next_line_start, $next_line_end - $next_line_start));

    if (!$next_line) {
        break;
    }

    // get the numbers
    preg_match($num_pattern, $prev_line, $prev);
    preg_match($num_pattern, $next_line, $next);

    if (intval($next['num']) - intval($prev['num']) <= 3) {
        // delete the "..." line
        $s = substr_replace($s, '', $offset-1, strlen($dots[0]) + 1);
        ++$dots_removed;
    }
}

print $s;
```

Comment: Thanks for trying. What about a brute force solution then?

Comment: Added my take on the problem.

Comment: Actually, you could use `preg_replace_callback()`, but use a lookahead for the next line so it won't be consumed.

Comment: complex857, it doesn't work when the string doesn't end with "..."

Comment: @Martin: It failed when the last line is not "\n" terminated.

Comment: @Wiseguy, great insight somehow slipped my mind, added a regexp based solution too.